# Is there anyway to "update" a CSS framework?

Tags: css, frameworks

I'm using Materialize CSS, however, I extensively modified it. They updated it and there are new functions that I need - however, I need to keep my changes. Do you guys know If there is anyway to "compare" them, and make what's diferente still different, so I can still keep my changes?
Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just take the new functions and add them into your modified stylesheet?

Comment: Yes but they are not like in the last lines, you know? They're spread through code

Comment: 1) Read the changelog, if available. 2) Look through the commit history in the official repository, if available. 3) Do a diff using any diff tool of your choice. 4) Don't modify a 3rd party dependency and instead try to override or extend in your userland code only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try: http://prettydiff.com/

Let me know if it helps.